# if else statement failing in a paper-rock-scissors challenge

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm a complete beginner in Javascript and coding in general.
I'm trying to make a simple command-line javascript paper-rock-scissors game but I keep getting a bug. I've created a function for the computer to randomly pick paper, rock or scissors and getting the user's selection from a prompt. To get the result I've written an if else statement that will show an alert with the outcome but regardless the input it always shows a tie. It seems that the code always ends up on the else part of the statement and I can't figure out why. Can someone help me with what's wrong with the statement and why it skips to else?

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let computerChoices = ["paper", "rock", "scissors"];
  let computerChoice = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];
  return computerChoice;
}

function playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection) {
  if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "paper") {
    alert("You win, paper beats rock!")
  } else if (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "scissors") {
    alert("You win, scissors beat paper!")
  } else if (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "rock") {
    alert("You win, rock beat scissors")
  } else if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "scissors") {
    alert("You loose, rock beats scissors")
  } else if (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "rock") {
    alert("You loose, paper beats rock")
  } else if (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "paper") {
    alert("You loose, scissors beats paper")
  } else {
    alert("even steven")
  }
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  computerPlay()
  const playerSelection = prompt("Please enter your choice", " ");
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();
  console.log(computerSelection);
  console.log(playerSelection);
  playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection);
}
```

Comment: Try removing `" "` from the prompt? because I just tested it without that and it's working fine for me

Comment: I just tested the provided code, without any changes, and it worked as intended as far as I can tell

Comment: Minor improvement: `playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection.toLowerCase().trim());` then in all of your conditionals you can just do `playerSelection` instead of `playerSelection.toLowerCase()` to trim down your code.

Comment: @TomGionfriddo that might have been because the space is there but selected by default (maybe only in some browsers?), so as soon as you type, the space gets overwritten.

Comment: Doing something like `["rock", "scissors", "paper"].includes(playerSelection)` would let you validate player input. The game delivers a tie when the input is invalid.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones You hit the nail on the head there. Apparently, in Firefox, the space is autoselected when the prompt opens.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `" "` from the prompt, it's adding an unnnecessary white space causing issues in your if statements

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let computerChoices = ["paper", "rock", "scissors"];
  let computerChoice = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];
  return computerChoice;
}

function playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection) {
  if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "paper") {
    alert("You win, paper beats rock!")
  } else if (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "scissors") {
    alert("You win, scissors beat paper!")
  } else if (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "rock") {
    alert("You win, rock beat scissors")
  } else if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "scissors") {
    alert("You loose, rock beats scissors")
  } else if (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "rock") {
    alert("You loose, paper beats rock")
  } else if (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "paper") {
    alert("You loose, scissors beats paper")
  } else {
    alert("even steven")
  }
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  computerPlay()
  const playerSelection = prompt("Please enter your choice");
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();
  console.log(computerSelection);
  console.log(playerSelection);
  playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection);
}
```

Comment: When I use `prompt()` with the second argument, the default is selected and typing replaces it. They must be clearing the selection before typing, so their input is appended after the default.

Comment: so, it's basically a typo

Comment: In short, I would say yes